# Multiline button and issue with alignment of ContentLayout icon xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms

I'm currently facing an issue trying to adapt my xamarin forms view buttons with icon to iOS version.

An image have a thousand words values so here is what i get now:

[image]

I firstly corrected the iOS behavior with the text appearing on one single line with the following renderer:

```
public class MultiLineButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UIKit.UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            Control.TitleLabel.TextAlignment = UIKit.UITextAlignment.Center;
            //if (Element.ImageSource != null && Element.ContentLayout.Position == Button.ButtonContentLayout.ImagePosition.Top)
            //{
                
            //}
            //    Control.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIKit.UIEdgeInsets(0, 50, 0, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

the buttons xaml is the following:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,40,0,0">
                <Button Text="Disponibilités de l'élève" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}" TextColor="{StaticResource Text}" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="10" ContentLayout="Top,20" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonWidth}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Command="{Binding OpenAvailabilityModal}">
                    <Button.ImageSource>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FASolid" Color="{StaticResource Text}" Glyph="{x:Static icons:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarDays}"/>
                    </Button.ImageSource>
                </Button>

                <Button FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="10" ContentLayout="Top,20" WidthRequest="{Binding ButtonWidth}" IsEnabled="{Binding OptionNotTaken}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Command="{Binding SubmitOptionCommand}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Secondary}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Text}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Poser une option"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ImageSource">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FARegular" Color="{StaticResource Text}" Glyph="{x:Static icons:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarPlus}"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGreen"/>
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Option posée"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ImageSource">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FARegular" Color="Green" Glyph="{x:Static icons:FontAwesomeIcons.CalendarCheck}"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Button>
            </StackLayout>
```

From my observations the contentLayout behavior is working as expected but when the text is too long, it go out of his parent component and so the icon remains centered in relation to the text position before the renderer act and center back the text inside the button.

I'm currently searching how to correct manually on the renderer the icon position to center it relative to button, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet, all i learned until now is i need to set manually the ImageEdgeInsets of the button control.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContentLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.contentlayout?view=xamarin-forms)  like:

```
<Button Command="{Binding YourCommand}" ContentLayout="Top,0" Text="Yourtext" Image="image.png" />
```